# Show/hide div with scroll, starting from bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code to show/hide div's when scrolling through website. My problem is that div appears when e.g. div `#top` reaches top of the browser's window. I need that `.news` div would appear when div `#top` is starting to show up in bottom of browsers window and disappear in the same way.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var topOfOtheDiv3 = $("#top").offset().top;
    var topOfOtheDiv4 = $("#bottom").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOtheDiv3 && $(window).scrollTop() < topOfOtheDiv4) {
            $(".news").show();
        } else {
            $(".news").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle i found http://jsfiddle.net/4r5kn/10/ Green box should appear, when blue one is starting to appear from bottom of the page.

Comment: can you also share the markup and preferably - create a fiddle example?

Comment: Just sec I got answer for you

Comment: Hey but everything is working as expected... at least watching your fiddle everything works. Can you please be more clearer what's the actuall problem, I can't really understand.

Comment: Hey skmasq, thank you for trying to help me, here's updated fiddle, maybe now you'll understand, scroll down and read the text inside. http://jsfiddle.net/4r5kn/10/

Comment: tried adding `$(window).height();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take window height into consideration too. I have [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r5kn/13/). The change is in deducting window height from `topOfOthDiv` and `topOfOthDiv2` variables.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var topOfOthDiv = $("#othdiv").offset().top - $(window).height();
    var topOfOthDiv2 = $("#othdiv2").offset().top - $(window).height();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (winTop > topOfOthDiv && winTop < topOfOthDiv2) {
            $("#dvid").show();
        } else {
            $("#dvid").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your window height to this.  This will make it so that the top of the div + the window height will need to be in view first:

Here's a fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/4r5kn/14/

1. I just added `var winHeight = $(window).height();` to your code,
2. added it to the if statement `if ($(window).scrollTop()+winHeight > topOfOthDiv && $(window).scrollTop()+winHeight < topOfOthDiv2) {`
3. and then voila.

This way, if you need to change or tweak the height at all (let's say you want it to show when the bottom of the div is in sight at the bottom of the page) you can add that pixel amount to your `winHeight` variable